# Setting up Hydrogen and Atom with Anaconda managing python installation

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, atom-editor, hydrogen

I have added my python 3 executable to the system PATH (against the advice of Anaconda) to try and get Hydrogen (and really any Atom extension/plugin) to run lines or blocks of code in Atom. The 'scripts' atom plugin appears to work (I select some code and enter `ctrl-shift-b`), but I'd love to use more of the features in Hydrogen. When I execute (for example):

```
print('hello world')
```

I get the following error:

```
Python 3

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "main", mod_spec) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in from ipykernel import kernelapp as app 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__init__.py", line 2, in from .connect import 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in import jupyter_client File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client__init__.py", line 4, in from .connect import 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 23, in import zmq 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq__init__.py", line 47, in from zmq import backend 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 40, in reraise(*exc_info) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise raise value 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 27, in _ns = select_backend(first) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in select_backend mod = import(name, fromlist=public_api) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py", line 6, in from . import (constants, error, message, context, 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have reinstalled the package, I've tried using the Anaconda power shell and normal prompt to install and load Atom. My only guess is that its having trouble launching a kernel, or am I supposed to launch one and then connect?

End goal:
run code block and it works.

Comment: Love Hydrogen... bummer on the issues. I use a Macos install, so might not be much help, but fwiw, I'll ask whether you can reproduce this error in any way outside of Hydrogen, e.g. via a similar IPython/Jupyter kernel? Sounds like Anaconda is working just fine for you? [This thread](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1405) if you're running python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

To use a Conda env as a kernel in Hydrogen you must register the env using `ipykernel`, e.g.,

```
conda activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

This creates an entry for the kernel in a default user-level location that is generically visible to any Jupyter instances run by the user (such as Hydrogen). It is recommended to also include a `--name NAME` flag to distinguish your different envs. Please refer to the `python -m ipykernel install -h` for more options.

Also, note that the minimum requirement for using a Conda env as a kernel is to install `ipykernel`. And, yeah, clean up the `PATH` so that it conforms to Conda best practices - there should be no need for manually editing.